# How do I group a number of sites (point geometries) together as a feature collection, to perform NDVI change calculations on all the sites?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, landsat

I am new to stack overflow and javascript, so apologies in advance.

The overall aim: calculate the NDVI change over time (inter- and intra-annual) at 8 sites using the landsat 8 image collection. Rather than do calculations on each one separately, I want to group the sites together and then do the NDVI calculation on all the sites at once (but get results for each site separately).

**Initial aim**: *filter for individual sites*. So, before doing the NDVI calcs, I need to first filter and reduce the landsat 8 image collection (to remove cloud, get the right dates, etc), including using `.filterBounds()` to filter spatially by site, as in the code below. When I run the code, only one image from the last site (site 5D) listed appears in the map window, and there are no error messages in the console.

```
//import the image collection
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_RT');

//define a list of geometry points with co-ordinates as the 8 distinct sites
var siteList = [
    ee.Feature(/* color: #166f12 */ee.Geometry.Point (135.78877, -15.146215), {name: 'site1A'}), 
    ee.Feature(/* color: #1f921a */ee.Geometry.Point (135.836993, -15.171145), {name: 'site1B'}),
    ee.Feature(/* color: #1c73d5 */ee.Geometry.Point (136.434148, -15.647369), {name: 'site2A'}),
    ee.Feature(/* color: #144882 */ee.Geometry.Point (136.441971, -15.650919), {name: 'site2B'}), 
    ee.Feature(/* color: #de2626 */ee.Geometry.Point (140.853576, -17.422561), {name: 'site4A'}), 
    ee.Feature(/* color: #911919 */ee.Geometry.Point (140.89625, -17.340024), {name: 'site4B'}), 
    ee.Feature(/* color: #23cf7b */ee.Geometry.Point (141.665424, -15.027324), {name: 'site5A'}),
    ee.Feature(/* color: #228c58 */ee.Geometry.Point (141.660919, -14.996538), {name: 'site5D'})
    ];

// Create a FeatureCollection from the list and print it.
var sites = ee.FeatureCollection(siteList);
print(sites);

//Define the image
var image = ee.Image(l8
  .filterDate("2014-07-01", "2016-09-30")
  .filterBounds(sites)
  .sort("CLOUD_COVER")
  .first());
print("Landsat 8:", image);

var vis = {min: 0, max: 14000, bands:['B5', 'B4', 'B3']};
Map.addLayer(image, vis,'Sites test');
```

**The question:** As the script shows, and following the GEE tutorials and other SO answers, I have defined the sites as point geometries, put them in a list, then defined a `ee.FeatureCollection()` as the list of sites. But something is obviously incorrect. *How do I change the script to make it work?*

I considered a possible workaround being filtering the image collection by `WRS_PATH` and `WRS_ROW` to get the images taken nearest the sites. Then define 'roi's' as polygon geometries and do the NDVI calcs within the polygons (I guess `clip()` image to polygon.

Hope that's enough info.

Answer (score 0):

You're only seeing one image because you only select one image using the `first` function.

There is a lot you need to do here, but here are some goalposts:

1. Create an NDVI composite for each image in the image collection using `map` and a custom function.
2. Mosaic the composites for a single date within the image collection (will be a little tricky, you'll probably have to define and iterate over the specific image dates).
3. Create an image from the composites-by-date by using e.g. `iterate` and `addBands`. (You'll have to store the date in the image name somehow so you know which date each band refers to in the final product).
4. Use `reduceRegions` on the feature collection and the multiband image you created to get values for each point for each image band.